# SocketException occur when open children form

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

I had develop an application with 2 `Forms`: `Form1` is the parent of `Form2`. And I redirect from `Form1` to `Form2` by following code:

```
Form2 settingsForm = new Form2(this);
settingsForm.Show();
```

And in `Form1`, I had start a `TcpListener`:

```
static IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())[1];
TcpListener smoClient = new TcpListener(ipAddress ,55962);
try
{
     smoClient.Start();

     MessageBox.Show("Connected");
}
catch (SocketException se) 
{
     Console.WriteLine(se.ToString());
}
```

But when I open `Form2`, `SocketException` is thrown:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Only one usage of
>   each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally
>   permitted    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoBind(EndPoint
>   endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Bind(EndPoint localEP)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start(Int32 backlog)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.Start()

How should I prevent this Exception or checked that `TcpListener` is started? Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guest your are re-creating your socket more than once and forgot to dispose that object properly. Remember that it can only bind one port per instance.

```
static IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName())[1];
TcpListener smoClient = new TcpListener(ipAddress ,55962);
try
{
     smoClient.Start();

     MessageBox.Show("Connected");
}
catch (SocketException se) 
{
     Console.WriteLine(se.ToString());         
}
finally
{
    smoClient.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will pay attention to __it can only bind one port per instance__. But TcpListener not have `Close()` function, bro ^^

Comment: you can also try to check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.exclusiveaddressuse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have Windows thinking your port `55962` is still used by an instance of your app which was closed long ago.

Try to use `smoClient = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 0)` - it will pick up first available port.

Comment: But my program have to connect with other and the port fixed is `55962`

Comment: In this case you should use `smoClient.Stop()`  to stop listener properly and release port.  (Btw, TcpListener is usually server, not client as it listens to connection, not connects to other points)

Comment: In this case, I have an existed program(client side) always connect to server which open listening at port 55962 so I can't change this port. Thanks for your advice, I will consider to `Stop()` listener and release port ^^